# Scanning a credit card with camera at checkout - Woocommerce & Stripe

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, user-experience

Anyone know if the above is possible? I am using an online store in a restaurant for table service (new because Covid). Anything I could use to cut down on time is going to make it easier for customers.

Something like this: https://www.chargestripe.com/scan-credit-cards-phone-camera/

I just can't find any plugins, but maybe someone else knows how to do it?

Comment: Not sure about the WooCommerce plugin ecosystem, if that supports this or not. If you're a developer and writing a mobile app integration, you could use a library like cardscan.io.
Or you can see if any Stripe Partners offer this capability: https://stripe.com/partners/apps-and-extensions